# How to stop Firebase Realtime Database Unity SDK listener load all child data at start of application

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an IoT project, with an arduino pushing sensor data to the realtime database. I am trying to connect an Unity app to listen to the last pushed value.

I started out using ChildAdd event listener and it works great. However, after the system running for a longer period, I have acquired large amount of historical data (a few MB) in my database. Now, whenever I relaunch the program, the app will try to load all previous data hence hang the application.

As explained by the User doc, "The ChildAdded event is raised once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path." Hence I tried to use ValueChanged event instead. I have another webapp plotting a realtime dashboard with the same method for web app. It only queries the last 300 values and works quite well. Still, my Unity app doesn't behave any better. I tested the following codes for database with a few entries, and with more than 10k entires:

1. I started with LimitToLast(1).ValueChanged on the reference node. This is basically what I wrote for the web app, only limited to fewer entries.

It works as expected under a few entires. However with more entry the app seems not listening to anything.

2. I added OrderByKey() since I suspect the data is not sorted, but still not helpful.

Whatever I try, when the dataset gets too large, the connected seems never got established. Even other listeners in the same app will fail. And when I stop the Unity editor and launch again, Unity hangs. This may signals an unclosed socket connection.

```
void Start(){

 FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("xxx");
 logR = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("logs");

 logR.LimitToLast(1).ValueChanged += HandleChildAdded;
}

void HandleChildAdded(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
        if (args.DatabaseError != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log((args.Snapshot.Value));
}
```

I'm expecting reading the latest data on Start, and listen for any subsquent new data. But when the existing dataset is large, the event handler is never triggered.

Is there a way to query only the latest data and not load all previous data on start? Or is Firebase Realtime database not suitable for my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar requirement in my project where I wanted to get only the latest chat messages to a user joining an already active chatroom. I used [timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/server-value#timestamp) to build a robust solution for this.

Database design:

- When every child is being added to the database, include a "timestamp" key in the child, with the value as "[ServerValue.Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/server-value#timestamp)". This instructs the Firebase Database to put the value for this key as the current timestamp on the server, and ensures that wrong timestamps are not stored due to local system time being wrong.
- Add a "Timestamp" branch to the root of your database with the value as the current server timestamp. This is required to get the current server timestamp on your Unity client reliably.

Unity Client implementation:

On Start(), get the current server timestamp by writing the timestamp to the database on the "Timestamp" branch.

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Timestamp").RunTransaction(mutableData =>
{
    mutableData.Value = ServerValue.Timestamp;
    return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
})
.ContinueWith(task => 
{
    long currentTimestamp = (long)(task.Result.Value);
    //Use this timestamp in the next step
});
```

Then use this timestamp to instruct the Database to send you children added only after this timestamp.

```
logR.OrderByChild("timestamp").StartAt(currentTimestamp).ChildAdded += HandleChildAdded;
```